# Where do I find the JavaScript API docs for window.IPython.*?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I wanted to be able to paste an image from the clipboard into IPython.

Being new to Python, but having solved this problem before in web-apps, I hacked a solution using JavaScript after spending a lot of time poking around in Firefox's inspector.

I found `window.IPython` and used trial-and-error to guess at which functions to avoid too much DOM hacking. I tried looking for documentation for the JS API but couldn't find anything.

Is there documentation for the IPython/Jupyter JS API somewhere?

Code FYI. Draft only but good enough for me. Use in your own notebooks at your own peril:

```
%%javascript

// remove the paste listener if it already exists
if (window.paste_listener)
{
    window.removeEventListener('paste',window.paste_listener);
}

// (re)declare the paste listener
window.paste_listener = function(event)
{
    if (event instanceof ClipboardEvent)
    {
        var file = event.clipboardData.items[0].getAsFile();

        if (file && file.type.substr(0,6) == "image/")
        {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onloadend = function() {
                var cell = IPython.notebook.insert_cell_below('code');
                cell.set_text("%%html\n<img src='" + reader.result + "' />");
                cell.execute();
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
}

// and add it
window.addEventListener('paste', window.paste_listener);
```

Comment: We haven't really documented the JS API yet, because it's still changing quite rapidly, and we don't want to give a false sense of stability.